# How can I fix "Filter error: bad id or parameters or duplicate filter" in NetCDF?

Tags: python, netcdf, netcdf4

I have been working on a project that uses NetCDF to store the trajectory of a simulation. However, when I try to run the simulation, I get this error:

```
RuntimeError: NetCDF: Filter error: bad id or parameters or duplicate filter
```

and I have been able to pinpoint this to second line of these two lines of code:

```
topo_var = traj_group.addVar(TOPO_VAR, uint_array_t, {frame_dim});
topo_var.setCompression(true, true, compression_level);
```

What exactly is this error saying and how should I go about fixing it?